# How to prevent pushing more than 2 buttons at once

Tags: android

I'm working on a memory card game and struggling with a problem. 
Technically, I can't directly disable Buttons because I can't predict which buttons the player will push. 
I allow the game to disable any button pushing after pushing 2 buttons, but if more than 2 are pressed I can't do anything.

Can you suggest anything?

Comment: Without code, we won't be able to help you with your specific problem.
What I would do: Set a "counter" - each time a `Button` is activated : `counter++`, before each `Click`: Check `if(counter =< 2)`. Only allow the activated `Buttons` to be clicked when `counter == 2`, to deactivate them and decrease `counter--`..

Comment: Updated sentence structure for improved reading

Answer (score 1):

Please try something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button mButton1;
    private Button mButton2;
    private boolean isButton1Press = false;
    private boolean isButton2Press = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        mButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                isButton1Press = true;
                if (!isButton2Press) {
                    Log.d("Button press", "button1");
                    //do something
                    isButton1Press=false;
                }
            }
        });

        mButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                isButton2Press = true;
                if (!isButton1Press) {
                    Log.d("Button press", "button2");
                    //do something
                    isButton2Press=false;
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: or you can use as well    if (!mButton1.isPressed())